# CGRect automatically resize after Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have some code in separate class, who bounded with UIView.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(20, 262, 139, 169);

[self setFrame:drawRect];

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithRed:125.0f/255.0f green:251.0f/255.0f blue:181.0f/255.0f alpha:1] CGColor]);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 200.0f/255.0f, 100.0f/255.0f, 100.0f/255.0f, 1.0f);

CGContextFillRect(context, drawRect);
```

But after clicking this view, size of UIView resizes to dimensions from interface builder model from my storyboard.

What does matter, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: Autolayout would be my guess.

Comment: There is no place that this code would make sense. You can't call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` outside of `drawRect:` and you mustn't call `setFrame:` inside of `drawRect:`. Where are you calling this code?

Comment: This code placed in function
`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`

I try to uncheck box "Autoresize subviews" on parent view (it's main view in app) and try to uncheck box on himself UIView, who maked by the above code.

Comment: @RobNapier you right about `setFrame:`, but if i want to make rects of this views use only code ability, when i must do it??? And what i must do, to shut off autolayout & autoresize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawRect:` is not the place to change the frame. If the system can't automatically handle resizing the frame (by scaling the view, for instance), then `drawRect:` is called in response to resizing the frame. If you could change the frame size in the middle of drawing, you'd have an infinite loop.

If you want the view to be in the rectangle `(20,262,139,169)`, then that's simple to put in autolayout. Just put the view where you want it, and create constraints to keep it there using Interface Builder.

If you don't want autolayout (not sure why you'd want to turn it off here, but if you did), you can turn it off and call `setFrame:` in `viewDidLoad`. But there's no reason to call it again in `drawRect:`.